# UITapGestureRecognizer is not working when tapping on image of UIImage view

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I create a log in view with func that I can pick profile pic when tap on Avatar as UIImage view, you can pick avatar from library.
As the code I wrote, I am not able to trigger the tapping gesture. 
Please be advised on this. Thanks 
[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[![enter image description here]

Comment: please add the code and format it instead of an image.

Answer (score 3):

By default UIImageView has disabled user interaction. Make sure it is enabled - either in Storyboard or programmatically.

[image: demo]

Comment: @All problem solved, I need to put the func setupAvatar in viewDidLoad(). it works Thanks